# (Architecture) Grabbing Data for angular2 app. Directly check MongoDB or my Java REST?

Tags: java, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, rest

I have a quick architecture question as this is one of my first web applications.

On the frontend I have an Angular2 NodeJS app, backend I have a Java server aggregating some data for me in a MongoDB.

**My question is simple. Should I create REST controllers in my java server to get data from the database? Or call the database directly from the Angular app.**

I am leaning towards the Java REST idea. I just feel it is more secure, easier to do, and *when I scale I can have processing done in Java* when a rest call is made.

But I am worried this may slow things down too much? I can directly call the database and get info to put on my angular site. Does anyone know if this is a real concern for speed?

Keep in mind the data returned from the calls could be thousands of lines of JSON and hundreds of objects.

Comment: *"Or call the database directly from the Angular app"* - No, never, not. The point is to de-couple the frontend from the implementation details of the backend, allowing you to, for example, change the structure of the data or even change the database itself, without adversely affecting the frontend (because you have an awesomely designed contract layer in between them). It also raises a swagger of security issues :P - not to mention sidestepping the business logic which should be managed by the server

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see. So basically frontend <-> service layer <-> DB. Service layer is what you are calling contract layer I believe? Also thanks for your help! Will take your advice

Comment: At a basic level, yes.  You're "service layer" may have a couple layers associated with it, but that's the basic idea

Answer (score 1):

I think you can benefit from checking out this link:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-your-first-application-mongodb-creating-rest-api-using-mean-stack-part-1

or

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/the-modern-application-stack-part-1-introducing-the-mean-stack?jmp=blog

As a side note - maybe it's just me - but I prefer Elastic to MongoDB - as it comes with Java-based REST API out of the box, and handles all the complexities of scalability and load balancing among nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Let me just say I appreciate your help. I checked out the links, cleared several things up for me!

Basically what you are trying to tell me is that most commonly people will use a MEAN stack and have express/node be the api to call to communicate with the Database? Looked like with express you could have some hefty queries and processing.

BUT, Iooks like if I need to do anything too complex I should use my JAVA server. Still trying to figure out how powerful/flexible express and the database modules are though.